# ActiveAdmin.register :as using wrong object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have two active admin controllers:

```
venture.rb
rent.rb
```

Both use the same model (`Ventures`).
They start, respectively, like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Venture
ActiveAdmin.register Venture, :as => 'Rent'
```

The form is generated by the same tag on both:

```
form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
```

But the input names are like this:

```
<input name="venture[field_name]" (...)>
<input name="rent[field_name]" (...)>
```

The problem is whenever I try to save.

The `venture.rb` works perfectly, while the `rent.rb` gives me the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: rent, (...)
```

I tried adding to `permitted_params` both ways:

```
permit_params :rent, (...)
permit_params rent: [ (...) ]
```

Neither solved the problem.

I get the idea that this part of ActiveAdmin is kinda hack-ish, and I have no problem with dealing with hacky things, but I have no idea how it's supposed to work, it's very poorly documented (I found an issue on GitHub, dropped more than a year ago), and some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you define your actions? Can you copy the controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, figured this out finally.

You can leave `permit_params`as it was on the "original, but you change the form tag like this:

```
form :html => { :multipart => true }, :as => 'venture' do |f|
```

Seems pretty simple right now, but it was pretty hard to guess this out.

Let's hope this helps other people.